# Why HikariCP creates new connection for every web app in Tomcat on startup

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, c3p0, hikaricp

When I define HikariCP with Tomcat 7 as JNDI inside context.xml like the below, every time I deploy new web application, it opens new connections to mysql server. For example, if I have 5 Apps in Tomcat, it will open 50 connections, 10 for each App. However, in C3p0, using the same settings and the same tomcat instance, it only creates a pool with 10 connections and share this pool with All Apps. I mean, in C3P0, the pool doesn't open new connection per APP while in HikariCP, it does. Was this done for a reason and is there anyway to change it?

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testDatasource" 
      auth="Container" 
      factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/football" 
      username="xxx" 
      password="xxx" 
      minimumIdle="3" maximumPoolSize="10" connectionTimeout="300000" maxLifetime="1800000" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented, tomcat loads the configuration in `context.xml` for each web application in the container. When you have 5 web application, HikariCP will be loaded for each application (5 times). So this behavior is normal with anything configured in `context.xml` file.

If you want HikariCP to load only once and regardless of the number of applications in the container, you need to define HikariCP JNDI in `server.xml` file not `context.xml`. This goes as the follwing:

Define HikariCP JNDI in `server.xml`:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
      <Resource name="jdbc/testDatasource" 
      auth="Container" 
      factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/football" 
      username="xxx" 
      password="xxx" 
      minimumIdle="3" maximumPoolSize="10" connectionTimeout="300000" maxLifetime="1800000" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Reference the JNDI resource in `context.xml`:

```
<Context>
   <ResourceLink name="jdbc/testDatasource"
            global="jdbc/testDatasource"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

Note: Using this setting will require restarting the web server each time you want to reload HikariCP setting. Redeploying the application will no longer result in reloading the HikariCP.

Comment: Good job!  Passing on knowledge.